# Removing Visual Studio's descriptive comments

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I use the VisualStudio's tool -> Search, to find a procedure from the source control, and i Open it, it says it is different from the one in the source control because it adds an unnecessary comment on top like this

```
==Scripting Parameters==

Source Server Version : Version105 (10.50.1790)
Source Database Engine Edition : Enterprise
Source Database Engine Type : Standalone

Target Server Version : Version105
Target Database Engine Edition : Enterprise
Target Database Engine Type : Standalone


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
```

What can I do to prevent this? I am using VS 2013 and I don't have SQL TOOLS> OPTIONS > SQL SERVER OBJECT EXPLORER.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what I found out is that you have to delete the visual studio's .dll file and develop a new one with some properties set to false. Sadly, I cannot give more info right now